# How to store values of selected columns in separate rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame` that looks as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ids': range(4),
    'strc': ['some', 'thing', 'abc', 'foo'],
    'not_relevant': range(4),
    'strc2': list('abcd'),
    'strc3': list('lkjh')
})

   ids   strc  not_relevant strc2 strc3
0    0   some             0     a     l
1    1  thing             1     b     k
2    2    abc             2     c     j
3    3    foo             3     d     h
```

For each value in `ids` I want to collect all values that are stored in the 
columns that start with `strc` and put them in a separate columns called `strc_list`, so I want:

```
   ids   strc  not_relevant strc2 strc3 strc_list
0    0   some             0     a     l      some
0    0   some             0     a     l         a
0    0   some             0     a     l         l
1    1  thing             1     b     k     thing
1    1  thing             1     b     k         b
1    1  thing             1     b     k         k
2    2    abc             2     c     j       abc
2    2    abc             2     c     j         c
2    2    abc             2     c     j         j
3    3    foo             3     d     h       foo
3    3    foo             3     d     h         d
3    3    foo             3     d     h         h
```

I know that I can select all required columns using

```
df.filter(like='strc', axis=1)
```

but I don't know how to continue from here. How can I get my desired outcome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `filter`, you need `stack`, `droplevel`, `rename` and `join` back to `df`

```
df1 = df.join(df.filter(like='strc', axis=1).stack().droplevel(1).rename('strc_list'))

Out[135]:
   ids   strc  not_relevant strc2 strc3 strc_list
0    0   some             0     a     l      some
0    0   some             0     a     l         a
0    0   some             0     a     l         l
1    1  thing             1     b     k     thing
1    1  thing             1     b     k         b
1    1  thing             1     b     k         k
2    2    abc             2     c     j       abc
2    2    abc             2     c     j         c
2    2    abc             2     c     j         j
3    3    foo             3     d     h       foo
3    3    foo             3     d     h         d
3    3    foo             3     d     h         h
```

Comment: Mmmh, I like this one more than mine; avoids the `apply` and the intermediate column (+1). :)

Comment: @Cleb: Thanks. Your `explode` is nice, too. Upvoted yours :) +1

Answer (score 2):

You can first store the desired values in a list using `apply`:

```
df['strc_list'] = df.filter(like='strc', axis=1).apply(list, axis=1)

0     [some, a, l]
1    [thing, b, k]
2      [abc, c, j]
3      [foo, d, h]
```

Then use [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) to distribute them over separate rows:

```
df = df.explode('strc_list')
```

A one-liner could then look like this:

```
df.assign(strc_list=df.filter(like='strc', axis=1).apply(list, axis=1)).explode('strc_list')
```